# How can I compare a date with current date using Doctrine 2?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a database where an "expiry date" is stored. Now I want the current date with the stored expiry date compared. If the current date is before the expiry date, the data should be displayed like usual, but if the data is expired, I want it to be excluded.

I tried:

```php
$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT d FROM test d WHERE d.expDate > :date')
    ->setParameters('date', 'now()');
```

Help would be cool, or some tips if someone understands my problem.

Answer (score 35):

There is another way:

```
$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT d FROM test d WHERE d.expDate > :today')
    ->setParameter('today', new \DateTime())->
```

Comment: In case anyone else is like me and doesn't often use `createQuery`, note that the format of the thing given as `test` above is a full namespaced name of your entity.  For example `SELECT m FROM MyProject\Entities\MyEntity m WHERE m....`. ([ref](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html))

Comment: This ends up being somewhat slower than `CURRENT_DATE()`, as in @Crozin's answer.

Comment: You can use DateTime because you need to modify the date like `new DateTime('- 5 days')` May be slower, but functional.

Answer (score 20):

Right now, you're comparing `expDate` column to the *text* "now()", not to the result of the function `now()`.

```
$em->createQuery('SELECT d FROM test d WHERE d.expDate > CURRENT_DATE()');
```

Comment: Mh now i get an exception which states "Error: Expected known function, got 'NOW' "

Comment: @Adi: My mistake. The function's name is `CURRENT_DATE()`, not `NOW()`.

Comment: `$em->createQuery('SELECT d FROM test d WHERE d.expDate > NOW()');`

Answer (score 3):

Actually, your way does work but you have a small error in your code.

You use:

```
$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT d FROM test d WHERE d.expDate > :date')
->setParameters('date', 'now()');
```

Now you can change by two ways so that it works:
**1. Leave the "s" at "setParameters"-> set Parameter**

Or

2. Use array when using "parameter**s**", in your case:

   ```
   $query = $em->createQuery('SELECT d FROM test d WHERE d.expDate > :date')
    ->setParameters(array('date' => 'now()');
   ```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `date` function to create a string to be compared:

```
$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT d FROM test d');
$query->addWhere("d.exp_date > ?",date("Y-m-d", time()));
```